# store looped data in separate variables in python?

Tags: python

i want to store looped data from a returned function into separate variables. here is my code
Please correct me if wrong

function:

```
 def rawi():
        a = raw_input("enter value of a")
        b = raw_input("enter value of b")
        return a, b

 #calling the above function:

 c = rawi()


 for i in c:
     print i
```

my desired output should be like :
variable1 should have the value returned from a
variable2 should have the value returned from b

thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you mean something like the following?

```
variable1, variable2 = rawi()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function should look like this if you'll loop through c:

```
def rawi():
    a = raw_input("enter value of a")
    b = raw_input("enter value of b")
    return (a, b) #you can return tuple/list/whatever that stores multiple variables
```

Comment: I like the parenthesis, but they aren't strictly necessary as the `,` operator creates the tuple.